Book about a girl traveling through a desert; dystopian future, magic
All I can remember is the girl left or got kicked out of the city. She left someone behind; boyfriend, brother, friend. She travels through what I believe was a large desert. She meets mercenaries or something along those lines. She falls in love with one of the guys. She ends up having magical powers where she saves the others during an attack of some sort. They might also have powers or special gifts. I think they might have been fighting a magical warrior that worked for the mayor or something of the city. She then goes back to the walled city for some reason and that's how the book ends.
There were others coming out but they weren't out at that time. It was a really good book. Came out between 2013 and 2017.
